# Insert blank line above or below the current line in Vim

Tags: vim, insert, mapping, lines, blank-line

I recently surprised myself wanting to insert blank lines above or below the current line either in normal or insert mode.

I usually add blank lines to my code for better reading or to properly separate blocks of code.

To do this I am using the following in my .vimrc:

```
" Add empty line above and below the current line
nnoremap <silent> <C-K> mP:pu! _<cr>:']+1<cr>`P
inoremap <silent> <C-K> <esc>mP:pu! _<cr>:']+1<cr>`Pa
nnoremap <silent> <C-J> mP:pu _<cr>:'[-1<cr>`Pa
nnoremap <silent> <C-J> <esc>mP:pu _<cr>:'[-1<cr>`Pa
```

The only ugly thing with these mapping is I'm using the marker P just to go back to the previous cursor position. I tried to use `` instead but it doesn't do what I expected.

Perhaps there is a slightly better solution otherwise this snippet works quite well for me.

I am slowly adding new mapping in my .vimrc. I noticed the `<C-[a-z]>` combinaisons are mostly free and the existing ones are pretty useless (i.e. `<C-Q>`, `<C-H>`, `<C-M>`…). Then I decided to bind them to new useful mapping:

```
<C-N> New file
<C-S> Save (:update!)
<C-P> CtrlP mixed mode
<C-S-P> CtrlPCmdPalette
<C-B> CtrlP buffers mode
<C-D> <C-C>ciw
…
```

Comment: Why doesn't `o` or `O` in normal mode do it for you?

Comment: For multiples reasons. In insert mode, I need to go back to normal mode then return to insert mode and get my cursor back to its original position I cannot archieve this with a single key stroke. <C-[a-z]> mapping are good because they are accessible from all modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using a named marker, you can use the backtick <kbd>'</kbd> to explicitly add a jump.  like:

```
nnoremap <c-k> m`O<esc>``
nnoremap <c-j> m`o<esc>``
inoremap <c-j> <esc>m`o<esc>``a
inoremap <c-k> <esc>m`O<esc>``a
```

Comment: Good one, I didn't know about m`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a robust mapping that also handles `[count]`, my [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) contains `]<Space>` mappings (among others). This particular mapping can also be found in the [unimpaired plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590).